# Calculation on a differential manifold

Tags: differential-geometry, manifolds, differential-forms

I do not know how to calculate:
Let $\alpha$ be a differential 1-form on $\mathbb{R}^{2}$ and let $V$ and $W$ be vector fields on $\mathbb{R}^{2}$. Compute $d \alpha(V, W)$ at the point $(0,1),$ where
$$
V=x \frac{\partial}{\partial y}-y \frac{\partial}{\partial x}, W=y \frac{\partial}{\partial y},
$$
and
$$
\alpha(V)=2 x-y^{2}, \alpha(W)=2 y.
$$

Comment: You need to use the formula $d\alpha(V, W) = V\alpha(W) - W\alpha(V) - \alpha([V, W])$.

Comment: Thank you. But I do not exactly know what \alpha([V,W]) means

Comment: For vector fields $V$ and $W$, the notation $[V, W]$ denotes the Lie bracket of $V$ and $W$, which is again a vector field. As $\alpha$ is a one-form and $[V, W]$ is a vector field, we can evaluate $\alpha$ on $[V, W]$ to obtain the function $\alpha([V, W])$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From
$$
\alpha(V)=2 x-y^{2}, \alpha(W)=2 y, V=x \frac{\partial}{\partial y}-y \frac{\partial}{\partial x}, W=y \frac{\partial}{\partial y},
$$
we have $\alpha=ydx+2dy$.
\begin{equation*}
\begin{aligned}
d \alpha(V, W)&=V\alpha(W)-W\alpha(V)-\alpha([V,W])=V\alpha(W)-W\alpha(V)-\alpha(VW-WV)\\
&=2Vy-W(2 x-y^{2})-\alpha(x \frac{\partial}{\partial y}+y \frac{\partial}{\partial x})\\
&=2x+2y^2-(2x+y^2)=y^2.
\end{aligned}
\end{equation*}

Comment: I think you got a sign wrong in your computation of $[V, W]$. I get $x\dfrac{\partial}{\partial y} + y\dfrac{\partial}{\partial x}$.